# On mac can I have more than one key for copy/paste commands

Tags: macos

I transition between Mac for development and Windows/Linux daily and I use settings->keyboard->"app shortcuts" to map my paste command to control-v instead of command-v, which works in most apps perfectly.

The problem is certain websites (for example jsfiddle.net) does not honor the remapping, so on that site and I cannot use EITHER control-v or command-v to paste, forcing me to have to right click my mouse to paste.

For these cases, I would prefer to not lose command-v, and to be able to paste with EITHER control-v or command-v instead of having to trade away command-v to use control-v to paste (same goes for the copy command control-c/command-c as well)

is that possible?